# Bose-Einstein function as real part of polylogarithm: $\overline{G}_{s}(x)= \Re \mathrm{Li}_{s+1}(e^x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, polylogarithm, cauchy-principal-value

For real $x<0$ the Bose-Einstein integral of order $s$ is given at https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12.E15 as

$$G_{s}(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(s+1\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s}}{e^{t-x}
-1}\mathrm{d}t$$

which can be written as a polylogarithm $G_s(x) = \mathrm{Li}_{s+1}(e^x)$. For $x>0$ this value of $G_s$ becomes complex. In an old paper from 1954
([On Bose-Einstein Functions](http://iopscience.iop.org/0370-1298/67/7/308))
J. Clunie defines the Bose-Einstein functions for $x>0$ by the Cauchy principal value

$$\overline{G}_{s}(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(s+1\right)}\lim_{\delta \to 0}\left(\int_{0}^{x-\delta}+ \int_{x+\delta}^{\infty}\right)\frac{t^{s}}{e^{t-x}
-1}\mathrm{d}t$$
(actually the pre-factor is omitted). The table for $\overline{G}_{1/2}(x)$ with $x >0$ can be reproduced numerically with Maple as $\overline{G}_s(x) = \Re \mathrm{Li}_{3/2}(e^x)$.

Is there a known proof that

> $$\overline{G}_{s}(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(s+1\right)}\lim_{\delta \to 0}\left(\int_{0}^{x-\delta}+ \int_{x+\delta}^{\infty}\right)\frac{t^{s}}{e^{t-x}
> -1}\mathrm{d}t = \Re \mathrm{Li}_{s+1}(e^x),\quad s>0, x>0  $$

I searched the internet without success for a relevant link, but perhaps there is a general result from complex analysis.

**Edit:** Thanks to R.J. Mathar's links I have the following argument:
Ng cites Dingle and gives the relation to the Fermi-Dirac functions (see https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12.E14)
$G_s(x)=-\Re F_s(x+i\pi).$  If we use the integrals in a heuristic way this gives for $x>0$

$$G_s(x) = -\Re F_s(x+i\pi) \stackrel{?}{=}
 -\Re \left(\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(s+1\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s}}{e^{t-x-i\pi}+1}\mathrm{d}t\right) =
 -\Re \left(\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(s+1\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s}}{1-e^{t-x}}\mathrm{d}t\right)=\Re \mathrm{Li}_{s+1}(e^x)$$

Is the second step justified? From the DLMF notation, I would think that the argument of $F_s(x)$ should be real in the integral form, otherwise they use $z$ for complex variables?!

Comment: isn't this 'just' a usual principal value integral?

Comment: @tired: Yes, but the open question is the relation to $\Re \mathrm{Li}_{s+1}.$

Answer (score 2):

This might basically be covered by the article by Ng, Devine and Tooper
in http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1969-0247739-X, Mathematics of computation 23 (1969) 639. Perhaps some combination of Robinson's paper http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.83.678 and
Lee's paper on polylogarithms http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.56.3909 also provide similar results.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I did not know the Lee paper. But in all three source I do not find an explicit computation of the principal value. Robinson's note is cited by Wood [The Computation of Polylogarithms](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/pubs/1992/110), but as far as see, there is no relation to the real part of the polylogarithm.

Comment: I found another argument, please have a look at the edited question.